# Aspect oriented programming - what is 'cflow'?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I have referred to the AspectJ reference [here](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/quick.html) it states that the 'cflow' is

> `cflow(Pointcut)` - every join point in
>   the control flow of each join point P
>   picked out by Pointcut, including P
>   itself

This isn't entirely lucid for me and I was wondering if someone could elaborate a little more on the meaning of cflow please? Why use it?

Thanks indeed.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

cflow helps you to advice the whole control flow. Let's try an example, I have 4 small classes

```
public class A {

    public static void methodA() {
        B.methodB();
    }

}

public class B {

    public static void methodB() {
        C.methodC();
        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;
        System.out.println( a + b );
    }

}

public class C {

    public static void methodC() {
        D.methodD();
    }

}

public class D {

    public static void methodD() {

    }

}
```

my aspect:

```
public aspect CFlow {

    public pointcut flow() : cflow(call( * B.methodB() ) ) && !within(CFlow);

    before() : flow() {
        System.out.println( thisJoinPoint );
    }

}
```

and my runner (just to see what happens):

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A.methodA();
    }

}
```

in my pointcut you could see `cflow(call( * B.methodB() ) )`, so I want to aspect control flow starting from `B.methodB` calling, and when you run Test class you see on console:

```
call(void test.B.methodB())
staticinitialization(test.B.<clinit>)
execution(void test.B.methodB())
call(void test.C.methodC())
staticinitialization(test.C.<clinit>)
execution(void test.C.methodC())
call(void test.D.methodD())
staticinitialization(test.D.<clinit>)
execution(void test.D.methodD())
get(PrintStream java.lang.System.out)
call(void java.io.PrintStream.println(int))
3
```

last string does not belong to aspect, it is just because of `System.out.println` inside `methodB`. All printed shows you control flow - chains of methods and 'events' (execution, calling, initializations...). You see, I started from `Test` class, which called `methodA` but they are not in 'stack', because we were interested in `methodB` control flow.

If you want to get that stack, but without first line (calling itself), you could try to define

```
public pointcut flow() :  cflowbelow(call( * B.methodB() ) ) && !within(CFlow);
```

cflowbelow is another pointcut, which means control flow excluding specified (in our case calling `B.methodB`).

Be careful to add `!within(_aspect_)` in pointcut, otherwise you will get nothing good but `StackOverflowError`. It happens because cflow can't be defined at compile time, and at runtime aspect belongs to control flow too (so it leads to eternal recursion...)

well, think of control flow as similar to call stack, then you will get an idea of its usage ;)