# Spring AOP: How exclude an unnecessary @Pointcut (@Around advice) execution due the execution from others @Pointcuts/advices

Tags: aop, aspectj, spring-aop, spring-aspects

I am working with:

- `Spring Framework` 4.3.3
- `AspectJ` 1.8.9

I have the following normal process:

- `@Controller` -> `@Service` -> `@Repository`

I have the following pair about `AOP`:

- `PersonaServicePointcut`

  - `PersonaServiceAspect`

The scenario is the following:

The `@Service` class has some methods such as:  `delete`, `save`, `update` and `findOneById`. They are declared **together** within the same class.

For the methods such as `delete` and `update` through `AOP` I am using a `@Before` or `@Around` advice to call the `findOneById` method.

The reason is that does not make sense *execute* the `delete` or `update` methods (consider Rest scenario) if the entity does not exist. Therefore through that `advice` an exception must be throw, lets say Exception **A**, it must be handled in a `@ControllerAdvice`

Practically the same approach for the `save` method has been applied. Therefore before to *execute* the `save` method **other** `@Before` or `@Around` advice is executed calling the `findOneById` method again. If the entity already exists an exception must be thrown, lets say Exception **B**, it must be handled in a `@ControllerAdvice`

Observe I have 3 points/3advices that use the `findOneById` method. It to check if exists an entity or not.

For example:

```
    @Pointcut(value=
    "execution(* mypackage.PersonaServiceImpl.saveOne(otherpackage.Persona)) 
    && args(persona)")
    public void saveOnePointcut(Persona persona){}

    @Pointcut(value=
    "execution(*  
    mypackage.PersonaServiceImpl.updateOne(otherpackage.Persona)) 
    && args(persona)")
    public void updateOnePointcut(Persona persona){}

    @Pointcut(value="execution(*  
    mypackage.PersonaServiceImpl.deleteOne(String)) && args(id)")
    public void deleteOnePointcut(String id){}
```

Again: these 3 advices use or *execute* the `findOneById` method.

The problem is when I add a new pointcut such as:

```
@Pointcut(value="execution(*    
mypackage.PersonaServiceImpl.findOneById(String)) 
&& args(id)")
public void findOneByIdPointcut(String id){}
```

I have created this pointcut to check if an entity already exists or not, if it does not exist it must throw an exception of type `C` (it for the classic 404).

Seems redundant *execute* the `findOneById` method through a `@Before` or `@Around` advice for the `findOneById` method itself. But I need this to `logging` and `audit` purposes and to create the exception of type **C** too. It must be handle by some `@ControllerAdvice`

The **problem** is when the others advices for the `delete/update/save` methods are executed (remember they call and *execute* the `findOneById` method too) my `findOneByIdPointcut` is executed *unnecessarily*.

I need change the pointcut declaration to indicate something like this:

```
@Pointcut(Alpha)
public void findOneByIdPointcut(String id){}
```

Where `Alpha` is:

execute the before/around advice for the `@Service`'s `findOneById` method, **but** *never* if its call has been done from the others advices from the
`PersonaServiceAspect` class.

I've tried many ways with `!execution` and `!within` combinations, but no results.

**Even** when I have created just **one** Pointcut that *intercepts* **all** the `@Service`'s methods with its respective unique `@Around` advice, and through the `ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint` parameter I am able to check what method has been called and then do the respective controls. But again this behaviour happens.

It means, through the following:

```
@Around("PersonaServicePointcut.anyMethodPointcut()")
    public Object aroundAdviceAnyMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable{
```

where `anyMethodPointcut` is `execution(* mypackage.PersonaServiceImpl.*(..))`

Is possible accomplish this approach? How?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exclude pointcuts within the control flow of a pointcut expression with

```
!cflow(<pointcut>)
```

In your example, you want to exclude those executions of the `findOneById` where the execution is inside the control flow of your own advice. If your advice is applied to the pointcut expression

```
@Pointcut("saveOnePointcut() || updateOnePointcut() || deleteOnePointcut()")
public void combinedPointcut() {}
```

you can exclude that with:

```
!cflow(combinedPointcut())
```

or to simply exclude all control flows from within the control flow of all advice executions, you could use:

```
!cflow(adviceexecution())
```

Your around find advice would look like this, based on the combined pointcut expression:

```
@Around("findOneByIdPointcut() && !cflow(combinedPointcut())")
public void aroundFind() {
    ....
}
```

Note that you can't combine the pointcut expressions in your example because they're binding pointcut arguments. You need to remove the `&& args(...)` parts and move them to the advice pointcut expressions directly. You can't combine binding pointcut expressions like `args(paramName)` with the `||` (or) operator so you'll need to create separate advices for those cases. You can still delegate most of the work from those advices to a single method if you want to. See an example of this kind of delegation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34426950/2699901).

Comment: Thanks a lot by the detailed explanation. Let me do the testing by my side. About the `binding pointcut arguments` I had some problems trying to mixing. So you are correct. Therefore, the following seems impossible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39730232/aop-combining-two-pointcuts-but-with-parameters-if-is-possible

Comment: Yes, you would get the `inconsistent binding` error message. But it's very easy to work around it, an example is show in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34426950/2699901). In my answer, you'll see examples of binding pointcut expressions for `@this()` and `@annotation()`, but the same applies to any other binding pointcut expression, `args()` in your case.

Comment: I am getting `org.aspectj.weaver.tools.UnsupportedPointcutPrimitiveException:` it because `cflow` is not supported by `Spring` such as is indicate here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-designators. Checking right now: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw

Comment: Is there other way to accomplish this? My `@AspectJ` use `@Transactional`. So even If I configure it about `Load-time weaving` it is not handle by Spring. Even more when my class uses `@Autowired`

Comment: I was able to resolve this without `cflow`. I did a refactor (there the true problem). But just curious if my previous comment is possible or not.

Comment: You need to decide if you want to stick with Spring AOP (reduced functionality and other limitations, i.e. it's proxy based) or go with full AspectJ. I had great success with AspectJ compile time weaving in my projects, you just have to configure your build accordingly. Load-time weaving should work too. It's quite easy to integrate AspectJ with Spring so this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Thanks by the update. I will do a deeper research. Not sure if `Load-time weaving should work too` would work with `@Transactional`

Comment: Yes, it would. I used spring transaction management with both load-time weaving and compile time weaving.

Comment: Thanks a lot by the confirmation. Just curious if you have a tutorial mixing these two approaches but through Spring `Java Config`. Seems mandatory until now use `aop.xml` within the `META-INF`

Comment: I can't come up with a tutorial right away, but the important thing when enabling Spring Transaction management with AspectJ is to use the `mode` attribute of the [`@EnableTransactionManagement`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html) annotation with the value `ASPECTJ`. Use of `aop.xml` is not mandatory AFAIK, the `spring-aspects` module, which contains the AspectJ transaction management code contains one though for it's own aspects.

Comment: Thanks, I will do a research. About the tutorial I mean if you know a good tutorial, through Google the results are from 2008 and 2010. Best Regards!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want the `findOneByIdPointcut` is not invoked inside you advice but should triggered in all other cases.

One way to do this is to use `call` in combination with `within` pointcuts. `call` will move join point up to caller method and `within` will exclude advice from target join points.

So your aspect code may look like this:

```
public class ControllerAspect {

    ...

    @Pointcut(value = "execution(* PersonaServiceImpl.deleteOne(String)) && args(id)")
    public void deleteOnePointcut(String id)
    {
    }

    @Pointcut(value = "call(* PersonaServiceImpl.findOneById(String)) && args(id)")
    public void findOneByIdPointcut(String id)
    {
    }

    @Before(value = "findOneByIdPointcut(id) && !within(ControllerAspect)")
    public void beforeFindOneByIdAdvice(String id)
    {
       //do some logic here
    }


    @Before(value = "deleteOnePointcut(id)")
    public void beforeDeleteOneAdvice(String id)
    {
        Persona persona = personaService.findOneById(id);
        //check that persona is not null
    }
}
```

Another way is to use `cflow` pointcut like described in @Nándor Előd Fekete answer, but you should note that in this case all `beforeFindOneByIdAdvice` join points below advice execution in the stack will be excluded too. So this can have some unexpected results for you in the future.

You can see how `cflow` works in "[Aspect oriented programming - what is 'cflow'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205916/aspect-oriented-programming-what-is-cflow)" answer.

Comment: Thanks again by your valuable support. I already have resolved this doing a refactoring. The trick is that the call of the `findOneById` must be do using the dependency of the beneath layer. It means through the `@Repository`. Therefore the advices about `save, delete, update` do not affect indirectly and unnecessarily the `find` advice. That was my mistake. The point is, the `Aspect` intercepts any call to a `@Service` method. From there each `Aspect`'s advice calls or execute the `findOneById` method through the `@Repository` dependency.